# How to capture the value of td of a table and put into the input field on click an edit button in angular 7

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a table whose data comes from loop.Here when I click on edit link an box will open with respective field as table.I need to capture the value of td of particular row into the input field of box same like edit functionality.For 'status' all checkbox should be there with checked value,for example if green is only there checkbox having green value will be checked other will be unchecked.Here is the code below

### home.component.html

```
<table>
<tr *ngFor="let user of users">
<td>{{user.id}}</td>
<td>{{user.name}}</td>
<td><span *ngFor="let item of user.Status;let j = index">
                    {{item.name}}
                    </span></td>
<td (click)="edit()" style="cursor:pointer">edit</td>
</tr>
</table>    
<div [hidden]="maindiv" style="background:yellow;padding:30px 10px;position:relative">
<span (click)="cross()" style="position:absolute;top:0;right:0;cursor:pointer">close</span>
<input type="text" name="id" placeholder="id"/>
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="name"/>
<span><input type="checkbox" name="green"/>green <input type="checkbox" name="green"/>red</span>
</div>
```

### home.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonserviceService } from './../utilities/services/commonservice.service';
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  getListData: any;
 dataGroup: FormGroup;
 selectedGroups: string[];
 maindiv:any = true;

  constructor(private commonserviceService: CommonserviceService) {

 }

  ngOnInit() {


  }
  users = [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "test",
    "Status": [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "green"
    }]
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "test2",
    "Status": [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "green"
    }, {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "red"
    }]
}];



  edit(){
      this.maindiv =  false;
  }
cross(){
    this.maindiv =  true;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should need to place button in the same `td` and pass the referrance variable via click function like below -

```
<tbody *ngFor="let user of users">
    <tr *ngFor="let item of user.Status;let j = index">
       <td><span>{{item.name}}</span>
       <span (click)="edit(item)">edit</span></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>

edit(dataItem) {
   console.log(dataItem);
}
```

Comment: I need to capture value of all column into particular input field of "id","name" "status" on click of edit link

Comment: @UIAPPDEVELOPER then you should wrap the code in `tbody` and iterate over the rows like in my updated answer.

Comment: when you copy my code and run it and click edit link,then only you can understand my question

Comment: Brother I have share the way you can do, just do little tweak around the code you will get your answer. Nobody here will write code for you but can give out the hint or solution. Hope you understand